# Rename TMUX window based on custom function in ZSH

Tags: zsh, tmux

I have a custom function in my `~/.zshrc` file:

```
function getCustomWindowName {
  # runs 'sed' on 'pwd' to get special dir name
  # and set it to $workspace
  if $workspace is valid; then
    echo $workspace
    return 0
  else
    echo ""
    return 1
  fi
}
```

In my `~/.tmux.conf` file, I **want** to do something like this:

```
set-option -g status-interval 5
set-option -g automatic-rename on
set-option -g automatic-rename-format '#{getCustomWindowName}'
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Bonus problem: if `getCustomWindowName` echos nothing (or `return 1`s), I want it to be the default window name. Is there anyway to do that as well?

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to accomplish, then I'm thinking that it might be easier to set the title *inside* the function using `tmux rename-window $workspace`.  Then call that function from inside the `zsh` prompt (see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/142099/get-function-into-ps1-zsh)).  If you want to optimize it, since it is called at each prompt, you could store the previous directory and only call `tmux renamew` when the directory changes.

Comment: That worked for my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned from NotTheDr01ds that I could just rename the window from ZSH, so I went with something like this:

```
function getCustomWindowName {
  # runs 'sed' on 'pwd' to get special dir name
  # and set it to $workspace
  if $workspace is valid; then
    tmux rename-window $workspace
  fi
}

# only allow unique values in this array
typeset -U chpwd_functions
# run this function when current working directory changes.
# Variables $PWD and $OLDPWD.
chpwd_functions+=(getCustomWindowName)
# Try to update when a new window is opened.
getCustomWindowName
```